# A duality with variance

Tags: probability, duality-theorems

I was working on a problem that essentially devolved to this:

Given $n$ successive occurrences of a Bernoulli experiment (say probability of 1 is $p$), find the expected number of runs (consecutive sequences of 1's). For example, 0 1 1 0 1 0 has two runs.

I approached this problem as a recursive idea, if $f(k)$ is the expected number of runs on $k$ occurrences, then $f(k) = (1-p)f(k+1) + \sum_{i=1} p^{i}(1-p)(1 + f(k+i+1))$- i.e. either we get a 0, in which case there's no run, or we get some number of ones followed by a 0, terminating the run. Playing with this recurrence relation got $f(k) = f(k+1) + p(1-p)$, and thus this expected number is $np(1-p)$. (I verified this in simulation)

I noticed this was equivalent to the variance of the binomial distribution, $np(1-p)$. Since this array of Bernoulli experiments is the definition of a binomial distribution, I thought this was too "nice" to be a coincidence, and was wondering if there was a duality/variance-based explanation for this (I couldn't think of one).

Thank you!